# I have to manually edit PR to set the correct base branch

Tags: github

On GitHub, I created my branch as follows:

[image]

Afterwards I created a PR corresponding to this branch.  That PR showed 'development' branch as the 'Source' (base), instead of the 'v6.0.0' branch which is what I had used as the base/source.

To fix this, I had to manually edit the PR on GitHub and reset the base branch as follows:

[image]

Did that PR initially show the base/source as 'development' because 'development' is set as the default?  (I am not the GitHub administrator, so I am not involved in that decision.)

Is there a better way so that the PR, from the get-go, shows the intended base branch and not the default base branch?

Comment: Please do not add "Thank you" or any other unnecessary noise in your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Github Pull Request docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request)...

> By default, pull requests are based on the parent repository's default branch.

---

> *Is there a better way so that the PR, from the get-go, shows the intended base branch and not the default base branch?*

Git branches don't remember what they were branched from, they're very simple labels.

Github could remember that information, I guess it doesn't. If it did, it would only work on branches made on Github.